# How many and which layers to Freeze while using Transfer Learning?

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, huggingface-transformers, transfer-learning

I am fine tuning the T5 model for QA task (NLP).

I would like to use transfer learning, to see if I can get better results.

Initially, I used the model like:

```
class QAModel(pl.LightningModule):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.model = T5ForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained(MODEL_NAME, return_dict=True)
```

Now, I want to change it and freeze some layers.

What is the best way to do it? Which layers should I freeze, and how many?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can freeze base model layers by setting `requires_grad` attribute to `False`.

```
if freeze_base_model:
            for param in self.model.base_model.parameters():
                param.requires_grad = False
```

```
model = QAModel(freeze_base_model=True)  # Set freeze_base_model to True to freeze the base model layers
```

You have try it out yourself, which layers to freeze and how many. It depends on the task and the model you are working with.